# Simplify multi toggle divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to simplify the code by not typing each `div` (`#TopicA`, `#TopicB`, `#main`, etc.) ID that is to be collapsed when an option is selected.

I would like all the `divs` besides the ones that trigger the button to automatically collapse. How can I make this happen?

Example: When I click `TopicA1`, I want to collapse all other `div`s, but I dont want to put all `div` IDs in JS code.

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qptwpay8/1/)

```html
<div id="main" class="QA">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <h3>Subtitle</h3>
        <button class="ClassButtonA">Topic A</button>
        <button class="ClassButtonB">Topic B</button>
        <button class="ClassButtonC">Topic C</button>
    </div>

    <div id="TopicA" class="QA">
        <h2>XX</h2>
        <button class="ClassButtonA1">Topic A1</button>
    </div>
```

```js
$(".ClassButtonA").click(function() {
            $("#TopicA").toggle("slow").trigger('reset');
        });
        $(".ClassButtonA").click(function() {
            $("#TopicB, #TopicC, #main").slideUp("slow").trigger("reset");
```

Comment: Use jQuery `$(this).collapse('toggle');` fuction. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/d5yck93t/3/

Comment: @SumitRidhal you should put that in an answer.

Comment: It's more $(this).siblings().collapse(), isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

A single function handles the toggle, and hides all siblings to the currently displayed div. Note that I did modify your structure some -- the content pane div now contains all the divs I wish to show/hide, thus leaving the button pane displaying. Hope it helps!

```js
// Event handler for click on any button el
$(".QA button").click(function() {
  // The text of the button matches the id
  //  of the div els, if I strip spaces.
  var toggleThis = "#" + $(this).text().replace(/\s/g, '')
  // Using the given string above, toggle that
  //  div el, and hide all siblings to that.
  $(toggleThis).show("slow").trigger('reset').siblings().hide("slow").trigger('reset');
});
```

```css
.QA {
  font: normal normal 14px/1 Helvetica;
  margin: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#TopicA,
#TopicB,
#TopicC,
#TopicA1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" class="QA">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <h3>Subtitle</h3>
  <button class="ClassButtonA">Topic A</button>
  <button class="ClassButtonB">Topic B</button>
  <button class="ClassButtonC">Topic C</button>
</div>

<div class="content-pane">
  <div id="TopicA" class="QA">
    <h2>XX</h2>
    <button class="ClassButtonA1">Topic A1</button>
  </div>
  <div id="TopicA1" class="QA">
    <h2>123</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="TopicB" class="QA">
    <h2>YY</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="TopicC" class="QA">
    <h2>ZZ</h2>
  </div>

</div>
```